# Changing font took boldness from section and subsection titles

Tags: fonts, bold

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Arial
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Arial
\titleformat{\thesection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
test
\subsection{Subsection}
test

\end{document}
```

I achieved to change font type to Arial but bold appearances of titles are gone. Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Bold for me with your example. Please save the example to a file called `oemerFonts.tex` and run it. Please post the log file of that run.

Comment: Please not, bananas are not apples and Helvetica is not Arial.

Comment: I am also unable to reproduce the issue you say you're experiencing. Please tell us which TeX distribution you employ.

Comment: in texmaker's quick build section in settings 
when I use 
xeLaTeX + view PDF
LuaLaTeX + view PDF
problem is still in there. But change to
pdfLaTeX view PDF
solve the problem for MWE but this setting can't compile my original doc.

Comment: With Lua/XeLaTeX, you need to use a different method of choosing fonts. See the `fontspec` way below.

Answer (score 3):

### Using fontspec

The `fontspec` package can load any TrueType or OpenType font, which include all the fonts you can use in a word processor.  It only works with `lualatex` or `xelatex`, not `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}

\titleformat{\thesection}
  {\sffamily\fontsize{12}{15}\upshape\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
test
\subsection{Subsection}
test

\end{document}
```

You can change `TeX Gyre Heros` to `Arial` if you want to use Arial.  They are similar, but not quite the same.  Heros is closer to what you get when you select `phv`, and computers with no Microsoft software might not have Arial installed.

### Using NFSS

The web page you found that claims that code will switch to Arial is not correct.  Arial and Helvetica are similar, but not the same.

You want the `helvet` package, which is part of `psnfss`.  You are telling the system to use the default PostScript Helvetica font, which on many systems is TeX Gyre Heros, [but you do not load any of the font encodings it supports](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/tex-gyre/doc/qhv-info.pdf).  If you check, you should be getting an error message that says the shape phv/bx/n is not available (because it’s looking for them in the wrong encoding). Here, I load the encodings T1 and TS1.

If you want to control which Helvetica clone the document uses, you can replace `\usepackage{helvet}` with `\usepackage{tgheros}`.  A version of Arial from URW might also be available, as [`\usepackage{uarial}`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/urw-arial).

I also took the liberty of redefining `\familydefault` rather than `\rmdefault`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Instead of OT1, which qhv does not support.
\usepackage{textcomp} % Also load TS1
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since April 2018.
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{helvet} % Likely tgheros.

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\titleformat{\thesection}
  {\sffamily\fontsize{12}{15}\upshape\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
\textsf{\textbf{test}}
\subsection{Subsection}
test

\end{document}
```

Comment: OP uses `phv`, not `qhv`.

Comment: Corrected the references to `qhv`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Running your example with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX issues

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/phv/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 9.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/phv/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/phv/m/n' instead on input line 11.
```

which clearly shows the origin of your problems.

With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you need `fontspec` for defining fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
test
\subsection{Subsection}
test

\end{document}
```

Note it's `\titleformat{\section}`, not `\titleformat{\thesection}`. And Arial is not Helvetica.

[image]